# How to approach this two dimensional array problem?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

[Problem (THE QUESTION)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wUNxn.png)

Strokes to paint 
Alex wants to paint a picture. In one stroke, Alex can only paint the same colored cells which are joined via some edge. 
Given the painting as a 2-dimensional array of letters indicating colors, determine the minimum number of strokes to completely paint the picture.

Example: The canvas height, h = 3 and width, w = 5 is to be painted with picture=["aabba", "aabba", "aaacb"]. The diagram below shows the 5 strokes needed to paint the canvas. It takes two strokes each for colors a and b, and one for c

```
a a b b a
a a b b a 
a a a c b
```

Function Description Complete the function strokesRequired in the editor below. The function must return an integer, the minimum number of strokes required to paint the canvas.

strokesRequired has the following parameter(s): picture[picture[0],...picture[h-1]] an array of strings where each string represents one row of the picture to be painted

Constraints

1 <= h <= 10^5

1<= w <= 10^5

1 <= h*w <= 10^5

len(pictureffl) = w (where 0 <= i < h)

picture[i][j] <- (a, b, c) (where 0 <= i < h and 0 <= j < w)

Hello.. so i attended one company interview and they asked me this problem and iam not getting any ideas please help

Comment: It can be solved by applying DFS/BFS. This question is a variation of number of islands problem which you can find here https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/find-number-of-islands/ . You will just need to modify your code a little bit. Ping me if you are not able to code it.

Comment: Start by exploring all the neighbours of a cell and include it into one stroke if it is as same value as current cell. Use a boolean array so that you can trace already visited cells.

Answer (score 0):

```py
class Paint: 

    def __init__(self, row, col, arr): 
        self.ROW = row 
        self.COL = col 
        self.arr = arr

    def visit(self, i, j, visited):
        ele = self.arr[i][j]
        for k in range(i,self.ROW):
            for l in range(j, self.COL):
               if self.arr[k][l]==ele:
                   visited[k][l]=True
                   v=l
                   if l>0 and self.arr[k][l-1]==ele and not visited[k][l-1]:
                       self.visit(k, l-1, visited)
                   if k>0 and self.arr[k-1][l]==ele and not visited[k-1][l]:
                       self.visit(k-1, l, visited)
               elif l>=v:
                   break
    # 2D matrix 
    def count_cells(self): 
        # Make an array to mark visited cells. 
        # Initially all cells are unvisited 
        visited = [[False for j in range(self.COL)]for i in range(self.ROW)] 

        # Initialize count as 0 and travese 
        count = 0
        for i in range(self.ROW): 
            for j in range(self.COL): 
                # If a cell value false then not visited yet 
                # then visit
                if visited[i][j] == False: 
                    # Visit all cells in the array
                    self.visit(i, j, visited)
                    print(visited)
                    count += 1

        return count 


arr = ["aabba", "aabba", "aaacb"]

row = len(arr) 
col = len(arr[0]) 

p = Paint(row, col, arr) 

print (p.count_cells())
```

Answer (score -1):

```
function visit(picture, i, j, visitedBoxes) {
    const currentElem = picture[i][j];
    if (picture[i][j] === currentElem) {
        visitedBoxes[i][j] = true;
        // go in four directions
        // south
        if (i + 1 < picture.length && picture[i+1][j] === currentElem && visitedBoxes[i+1][j] === false) {
            visit(picture, i+1, j, visitedBoxes);
        }
        // west
        if (j+ 1 < picture[i].length && picture[i][j+1] === currentElem && visitedBoxes[i][j+1] === false) {
            visit(picture, i, j+1, visitedBoxes);
        }
        // north
        if (i > 0 && picture[i-1][j] === currentElem && visitedBoxes[i-1][j] === false) {
            visit(picture, i-1, j, visitedBoxes);
        }
        // west
        if (j > 0 && picture[i, j-1] === currentElem && visitedBoxes[i, j-1] === false) {
            visit(picture, i, j-1, visitedBoxes);
        }
    }
}

function countStrokes(picture) {
    const visitedBoxes = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < picture.length; i++) {
        visitedBoxes[i] = [];
        for(let j = 0; j < picture[i].length; j++) {
            visitedBoxes[i][j] = false;
        }
    }
    let srokesCount = 0;
    for (let i = 0; i < picture.length; i++) {
        for (let j = 0; j < picture[i].length; j++) {
            if (!visitedBoxes[i][j]) {
                visit(picture, i, j, visitedBoxes);
                srokesCount++;
            }
        }
    }
    console.log('Strokes Count', srokesCount);
}

countStrokes(['aaaba', 'ababa', 'aacba']);
```

This will output 5.

Also you can use

```
function printVisited(visitedBoxes) {
    for (let i = 0; i < visitedBoxes.length; i++) {
        let str = ''
        for(let j = 0; j < visitedBoxes[i].length; j++) {
            str += visitedBoxes[i][j] ? '1 ': '0 ';
        }
        console.log(str);
    }
    console.log('-------------');
}
```

to print after each loop.

Output

```
1 1 1 0 0 
1 0 1 0 0 
1 1 0 0 0 
-------------
1 1 1 1 0 
1 0 1 1 0 
1 1 0 1 0 
-------------
1 1 1 1 1 
1 0 1 1 1 
1 1 0 1 1 
-------------
1 1 1 1 1 
1 1 1 1 1 
1 1 0 1 1 
-------------
1 1 1 1 1 
1 1 1 1 1 
1 1 1 1 1 
-------------
Strokes Count 5
```